Run spearman correlation using tidyverse for a each feature with following data structure
I have a data frame with about 700 columns with columns 1:699 features and the last column is the group designation (A or B). What I intend to do is to run multiple correlation between the groups for each of the column features.
My data is something like the following:
   speed  distance  mpg car_group
    120   3000      25   A
    110   3040      35   A
    .      .        .
    .      .        .
    .      .        .
    .      .        .
    70   4000      50    B
    73   5000      30    B


 The code that I have written: 
 data %>% 
     pivot_longer(!car_group, names_to = 'Feature', values_to = 'value') %>%
     nest(Feature) %>% 
     dplyr::mutate(
        fit = map(data, ~cor.test(car_group,value,method = 'spearman', data=.x)),
        tidied = map(fit,tidy),
      ) %>%
    unnest(tidied)
     

The cor.test function cannot fit the correlation since it expects two numerical columns.
What is the best way to implement?
Thank you so much!

You could try the package {longpairs}.
It can be installed from github with:
remotes::install_github("the-mad-statter/longpairs")

With it you can do:
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(longpairs)

# example data structured like yours
data <- data.frame(
  feature_1 = rnorm(12),
  feature_2 = rnorm(12),
  group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4)
)

# add a within-group id column so that observations can be paired across groups
data <- mutate(data, id = row_number(), .by = group)

# gives 2 features for 3 groups with 4 observations in each group
data
#>     feature_1  feature_2 group id
#> 1   0.1754705 -2.8107294     A  1
#> 2   1.4420969  0.5529971     A  2
#> 3  -0.7579963 -0.1575507     A  3
#> 4  -0.4952094  0.1437159     A  4
#> 5  -0.3314862 -1.1084660     B  1
#> 6  -0.5451988 -0.9347023     B  2
#> 7   0.6777968 -0.8703266     B  3
#> 8  -1.9352026 -1.3790664     B  4
#> 9   0.1222580  0.3295008     C  1
#> 10  0.5840774 -2.4161328     C  2
#> 11 -2.0389680 -1.2761218     C  3
#> 12  0.7315441  0.4844478     C  4

# names of feature columns
features <- setdiff(names(data), c("id", "group"))

# row bind (i.e., map_dfr()) lp_cor() output across features because 
# lp_cor() is only programmed to deal with one feature at a time
# 
# select name1, name2, and estimate columns because lp_cor() outputs additional
# information from cor.test() as well as optional descriptive statistics, but 
# you are only interested in the estimate (i.e., correlation)
map_dfr(
  features,
  ~ {
    bind_cols(
      data.frame(feature = .),
      lp_cor(data, !!., group, id, descriptives = FALSE, method = "spearman") %>% 
        select(name1, name2, estimate)
    )
  }
)
#>     feature    name1    name2 estimate
#> 1 feature_1 group==A group==B     -0.4
#> 2 feature_1 group==A group==C      0.4
#> 3 feature_1 group==B group==C     -1.0
#> 4 feature_2 group==A group==B      0.0
#> 5 feature_2 group==A group==C     -0.4
#> 6 feature_2 group==B group==C     -0.8

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0

You may be interested in using the corrr package from tidymodels, as it handles dataframes well:
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)

df <- tibble(
  feature_1 = rnorm(15),
  feature_2 = rnorm(15),
  group = sample(c("A", "B"), size = 15, replace = TRUE)
)

df |> 
  nest(data = !group) |> 
  mutate(corrs = map(data, correlate)) |> 
  unnest(corrs)
#> Correlation computed with
#> • Method: 'pearson'
#> • Missing treated using: 'pairwise.complete.obs'
#> Correlation computed with
#> • Method: 'pearson'
#> • Missing treated using: 'pairwise.complete.obs'
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   group data             term      feature_1 feature_2
#>   <chr> <list>           <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 B     <tibble [7 × 2]> feature_1    NA        -0.285
#> 2 B     <tibble [7 × 2]> feature_2    -0.285    NA    
#> 3 A     <tibble [8 × 2]> feature_1    NA        -0.342
#> 4 A     <tibble [8 × 2]> feature_2    -0.342    NA

Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0
